# I am not able to access the Action bar in Activity

Tags: android

I am facing issues in accessing Action bar in one of my android activity and getting below error.Please find the below code.Kindly help me resolve the issue and let me know what mistake i have made. Thanks for your help!!!

Error Message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{blueman.vetri.com.materialtest/blueman.vetri.com.materialtest.ui.Task1}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

1) Activity

```
public class Task1 extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar1;
private Button leave_your_bed;
private Button find_a_place;
private Button opening;
private Button practice;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(blueman.vetri.com.materialtest.R.layout.activity_task1);
    leave_your_bed=(Button)findViewById(blueman.vetri.com.materialtest.R.id.leave_your_bed);
    find_a_place=(Button)findViewById(blueman.vetri.com.materialtest.R.id.find_a_place);
    opening=(Button)findViewById(blueman.vetri.com.materialtest.R.id.opening);
    practice=(Button)findViewById(blueman.vetri.com.materialtest.R.id.practice);

    leave_your_bed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LeaveYourBed.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    find_a_place.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FindPlace.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
    opening.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Opening.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    practice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Practice.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    toolbar1 = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar1);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
}
```

2)app_bar xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
  android:theme="@style/MyCustomToolBarTheme"
>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

3)Style.xml file:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomToolBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#000</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: i don't see any `id` with `app_bar` in XML

Comment: Thanks.However i still not able to access action bar even if i added "id"

Comment: have you included toolbar in your activity xml

Comment: Thanks Vivek..I found my mistake ..I did not include action bar in activity XML

Answer (score 0):

Move your code which sets the `ActionBar` to right underneath your `super.onCreate`, and add the following lint check:

```
toolbar1 = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar1);

if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

Add the following to your `app_bar.xml` file:

```
android:id="@+id/app_bar"
```

One of these solutions should fix the NPE.

Comment: Hi Nick, I tried both of the solution but i still not able to access the Action bar. If i use the first solution i can access the activity but no action bar is displaying..Kindly let me know if i need to change anything?